# Facebook login auth code calling loop function twice

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, authentication

The Facebook Graph API code I am using to login users is calling my `getfriends()` loop function twice. How can I change the code so that the loop function is only called once, whilst still allowing users in various states to login?

```
    <html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head> 
<title>FB App</title> 
<script> 
var userList = [];
    userCount = 0;

function getfriends () {
    console.log("getFriends");
    var url = "/me/friends";
    FB.api(url, function (response) {
        userList = userList.concat(response.data);
        userCount = response.data.length;
        compareAllFriends();
    });
}

function compareAllFriends () {
    console.log("compareAllFriends");
    var i = 0, l = 10, userID;
    for (; i < l; i += 1) {
        userID = userList[i].id;
        compareFriendsWith (i, userID);
    }
}
function compareFriendsWith (i, id) {
    console.log("compareFriendsWith", i, id);
}

</script> 
</head> 
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<p align="right"><button id="fb-auth">Login</button></p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({ appId: 'APP_ID', 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});

  function updateButton(response) {
    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

    if (response.authResponse) {
      //user is already logged in and connected
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        getfriends();
        button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
      });
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.logout();
      };
    } else {
      //user is not connected to your app or logged out
      button.innerHTML = 'Login with Facebook';
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me');
          } else {
            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
          }
        }, {scope:''});     
      }
    }
  }

  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    
};

(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol 
    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
// ]]></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the problem may be that `updateButton()` is run more than once and that in turn calls `getfriends()` more than once.

Judging from [the Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/), since you set `status: true` in `init()`, you don't need this line:

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
```

That will happen automatically in the next line where you invoke `subscribe()`.  So that's probably why you're seeing `getfriends()` executed twice.

If that doesn't work, a quick but much less elegant workaround might be to have a variable like `hasfriends`, initialize it to `false`, check its value inside of `getfriends()`, and have `getfriends()` do nothing if it's `true`.  If it's `false`, set it to `true` in `getfriends()` so the main code in `getfriends()` only runs once.

Comment: I spoke too soon. Removing that line fixed the problem, but then users who are not already logged into Facebook can't log into the app. Without that line you need to log into Facebook first as the log in button doesn't work.